# IWTL how export outlook emails (that contains table) to excel

Tags: python, outlook, export-to-excel, win32com, office-automation

I have written the following code to read last email from outlook:

```
import win32com.client
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

for account in mapi.Accounts:
    print(account.DeliveryStore.DisplayName)

inbox = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
```

But, the 'message.body' is a string in the following format:

```
'Team,\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\nToday’s Activity Details: 04-03-2023\r\n\r\nS/N\r\n\r\nPackage/Area\r\n\r\nActivity Details\r\n\r\nStatus\r\n\r\nEngineer\r\n\r\nContract\r\n\r\n1\r\n\r\nG12\r\n\r\nPlant LLF and Routine Job\r\n\r\nCompleted\r\n\r\nSam\r\n\r\nMark\r\n\r\nNext Working day’s Activity Planning: 06-03-2023\r\n\r\n1\r\n\r\nG13\r\n\r\nPlant LLF and Routine Job\r\n\r\nPending\r\n\r\nSam\r\n\r\nMark\r\n\r\n2\r\n\r\nG14\r\n\r\nPM of Comp\r\n\r\nPending\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n \r\n\r\nRegards.\r\n'
```

The email actually looks like this:

[Screenshot of email body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8siP.png)

I want to export message.body in tabular format to excel. Can anyone please help?

P.S. I am total beginer to using python for system interactions.

I tried searching on forum, and found the following way but this only allows exporting all content in one cell:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.Workbook() 
sheet = wb.active 

c1 = sheet.cell(row = 1, column = 1) 
c1 = message.body
wb.save("demo.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to read the `MailItem.HTMLBOdy` property (instead of plain text `Body`), parse or load it into an `HTMLDocument2` object, and then extract the data from the HTML table.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware, the `Body` property returns a plain text string without any formatting the message body may contain. If you need to preserver any table formatting like colors, font and etc. you need to deal with the `HTMLBody` property instead.

The Outlook object model supports three main ways of customizing the message body:

1. The [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-body-property-outlook) property returns or sets a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. The [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-htmlbody-property-outlook) property of the `MailItem` class returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Setting the `HTMLBody` property will always update the `Body` property immediately.
3. The Word object model can be used for dealing with message bodies. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.

So, you may use the Word object model to copy the table from the message body and pasting with all formatting embedded to the Excel document. Just a regular copy&paste operation between Office applications.